# I keep getting this error on my discord bot: 'HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request.'

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

What does this mean, and how do I fix it, I know for a fact my code is correct and nothing is wrong with it, I checked with multiple friends. I have no idea why this is happening and I need my bot to start working soon.

Comment: It could be that someone closes the discord window mid-request; in that case there's nothing to do about it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an error happening within the discord.js library if a web request is stuck for a long time, which might happen due to an outage or bad internet connection. Those connections are killed with that error message to free resources.

Those errors should not be fatal and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding flame’s point - put your code in a try catch statement e.g.

```js
try {
//code
} catch (error) {
//error code for example
console.log('an error has occurred')
//if you want no error has occurred log
console.log('')
// ^ will not log anything
}
```

Alternatively, I’ve researched that it could be something to do with a directory not being referenced properly, so check your code for that.

Hope I helped