# A role assigning bot doesn't sometimes remove a role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wanted to create a bot to assign users a role depending on the language they speak for a bilingual server, but if i try to give myself the czech role, it gives me the role, but doesn't remove the rest:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel.name == 'bot') {
    var sender = msg.guild.members.resolve(msg.author.id);

    if (msg.content == 'english' || msg.content == 'bilingual' || msg.content == 'czech') {
      sender.roles.remove(['719865762453389344', '719865894733479936', '719866013524688926']);
      switch (msg.content) {
        case 'czech':
          sender.roles.add(['719865762453389344']);
          console.log("czech");
          break;
        case 'bilingual':
          sender.roles.add(['719865894733479936']);
          console.log("bilingual");
          break;
        case 'english':
          sender.roles.add(['719866013524688926']);
          console.log("english");
          break;
        default:
      }
    }
    msg.delete();
  }
});

client.login('CENSORED');
```

with a scary error

```
(node:16796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AbortError: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\CENSORED\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:107:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:16796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)
```

I know there are unhandled things all over the place, you can of course blame me and even point them out, but i plan to handle them later on, for now i want to get the basic structure done.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a try-catch block:

```
try {
  // code
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
};
```

It's possible that the user closed the Discord window mid-request ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889245/i-keep-getting-this-error-on-my-discord-bot-httperror-aborterror-the-user-a)), which in that case, there is indeed nothing to do about it other than handle the error appropriately.

Another thing I'd advise doing is instead of declaring the `sender` variable, just use `msg.member`. When adding only one role to a member, you don't need to pass in array, just a single string.

Comment: That's a helpful thing, but doesn't solve my core problem, the error is, how i later discovered, mostly my fault and would be rare to see in the real world. The real thing i want to address, is that i can't simultaneously remove someones role and give him another. I can't use .set, because i want to remove only certain roles.

Answer (score 0):

I found out later, that for some reason, delaying the adding of the role fixes the problem, like so:

```
sender.roles.remove(['719865762453389344', '719865894733479936', '719866013524688926']);
setTimeout(function(){
  sender.roles.add(['719865762453389344']);
}, 500);
```

not the most ideal or scalable solution, but it seems to work fine for now.