# discord.js bot newly returns HTTPError 500 several times a day

Tags: discord.js

I've run a couple of discord.js bots for friends over the past several years with no issues (one is in 2 servers and one is in 12), but starting around September 24th, 2022, these bots fail roughly ~8 times a day with an error such as the following:

```
HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:201:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/[channel id here]/messages',
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: '[message content here]',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:201
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
              ^
```

More often for deletions:

```
HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:201:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:210:5)
    at async Message.delete (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:792:5) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/[channel id here]/messages/[message id here]',
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:201
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
              ^
```

I have [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) set up to restart my bots when they crash due to this, though it takes a few minutes to take effect, during which time others just see my bots as unavailable for ~5 mins.

I also know Discord changed to slash commands, but that's only for bots in >75 servers, which mine are not.  Again, this problem randomly started happening one day with no changes made by me.

I did see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351220) that says HTTPErrors should be caught and ignored (I guess...inside my `.on("messageCreate"` or `.on("messageDelete"` functions? I wasn't sure where to put it) but that still causes the issue where the current message creation/deletion fails to occur.

My question(s):

- Is HTTPError 500 easily avoidable, like did I miss a change somewhere?  It's weird that this went from "never occurs, for years" to "happens 8 times a day for the Discord API timing out".
- If I were to catch the problem instead, is it okay to retry the request, and is there a trivial way to do so?  I assume if I refactor message sending/deletion to a single function with a try-catch where the catch block retries the send, that might work...does that sound feasible?

Thanks much!

Comment: The Discord API is constantly being updated as well as Discord.JS. How often do you update your code? If not frequently, you may be running out-of-date code and API calls. Also, keep in mind Discord now has privileged intents for message content (more on that [here](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ)).

Comment: Elitezen: Thanks!  I update it every so often just to catch up on the latest bugfixes and whatnot.  I just updated discord.js major versions not too long ago.  Thanks for notice about message content privileged intents, but that page says "Unverified bots in fewer than 100 servers are not affected at all", which would include mine (2 and 12), so that's definitely not it.